# Sharepoint 2010 foundation search error, licensing issues

Tags: search, licensing

I'm having problems with the search on my new sharepoint farm. It seems to be licensing related. I need to know how and/or what to configure appropriately, basically how to solve this.

There's a web service application based on Sharepoint Foundation that makes use of the search to look up content and represent the results. Since on my previous farm everything runs fine it's not a coding problem. The message I recieve when trying to do any kind of search through the web service app is:

> This farm is configured with a topology that is not supported by your Microsoft Search Server 2010 Express software license. Contact your administrator to configure your Search Service Application with one partition and index/query components on the same application server or upgrade your software license to an advanced SKU.

This is what I get from calling the web service search method from SoapUI. Trying to do any search from within sharepoint yields a much less verbose error message:

> Internal server error exception:
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: 63870f3b-3207-4bba-8dc4-dcc0c03182a3
>
> Date and Time: 4/23/2012 9:56:27 PM

Comment: What do the logs show for that correlation ID?